# Powershell - How to pass variable into scriptblock

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I'm trying to understand and figure out how I can pass a variable into a scriptblock. In my below example script, when a new file is dropped into the monitored folder it executes the $action script block. But the $test1 variable just shows up blank. Only way I can make it work is by making it a global variable, but I don't really want to do that.

I've looked into this some and I'm more confused than when I started. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction to understand this?

```
$PathToMonitor = "\\path\to\folder"

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter  = "*.*"
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false

$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$test1 = "Test variable"

$Action = {
    Write-Host "$test1"
}

$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreateConsumer
}

try {
    do {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 5
    } while ($true)
}
finally {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreateConsumer
    
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden away in the documentation for [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.2), way down in the [`-Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) parameter description is this little tidbit:

> The value of the Action parameter can include the $Event, $EventSubscriber, $Sender, $EventArgs, and $Args automatic variables. These variables provide information about the event to the Action script block. For more information, see about_Automatic_Variables.

What this means is PowerShell automatically creates some variables that you can use inside the event handler scriptblock and it populates them when the event is triggered - for example:

```
$Action = {
    write-host ($Sender | format-list * | out-string)
    write-host ($EventArgs | format-list * | out-string)
}
```

When you create a file in the watched folder you'll see some output like this:

```
NotifyFilter          : FileName, DirectoryName, LastWrite
Filters               : {*}
EnableRaisingEvents   : True
Filter                : *
IncludeSubdirectories : False
InternalBufferSize    : 8192
Path                  : c:\temp\scratch
Site                  :
SynchronizingObject   :
Container             :




ChangeType : Created
FullPath   : c:\temp\scratch\New Text Document (3).txt
Name       : New Text Document (3).txt
```

If these contain the information you're after then you don't actually need to pass any parameters into the scriptblock yourself :-).

**Update**

If you still need to pass your own variables into the event you can use the `-MessageData` parameter of `Register-ObjectEvent` to be able to access it as `$Event.MessageData` inside your event scriptblock - for example:

```
$Action = {

    write-host ($EventArgs | format-list * | out-string)

    write-host "messagedata before = "
    write-host ($Event.MessageData | ConvertTo-Json)

    $Event.MessageData.Add($EventArgs.FullPath, $true)

    write-host "messagedata after = "
    write-host ($Event.MessageData | ConvertTo-Json)

}

$messageData = @{ };
$handlers = . {
    # note the -MessageData parameter
    Register-ObjectEvent `
        -InputObject      $FileSystemWatcher `
        -EventName        Created `
        -Action           $Action `
        -MessageData      $messageData `
        -SourceIdentifier FSCreateConsumer
}
```

which will output something like this when the event triggers:

```
ChangeType : Created
FullPath   : c:\temp\scratch\New Text Document (16).txt
Name       : New Text Document (16).txt



messagedata before =
{}
messagedata after =
{
  "c:\\temp\\scratch\\New Text Document (16).txt": true
}
```

`$messageData` is technically still a global variable but your `$Action` doesn't need to know about it anymore as it takes a reference from the `$Event`.

Note you'll need to use a *mutable* data structure if you want to persist changes - you can't just assign a new value to `$Event.MessageData`, and it'll *possibly* need to be thread-safe as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I'm trying to solve is that sometimes the FileSystemWatcher triggers twice in a row for the same new file. I thought maybe I'll use a hashtable to store the filenames and timestamps, then use that to prevent the double up that sometimes occurs. But I've been unsuccessful unless I make the hashtable a global variable.

Comment: @xeric080 - updated to use ```-MessageData``` parameter.

Comment: Cool idea, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The event action block runs on a background thread and can't resolve `$test1` when dispatched.

One workaround is to explicitly read from and write to a globally-scoped variable (eg. `Write-Host $global:test1`), but a better solution is to ensure the `$Action` block "remembers" the value of `$test1` for later - something we can accomplish with [a *closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

We'll need to reorganize the code slightly for this, so start by replacing the `$test1` string literal with a synchronized hashtable:

```
$test1 = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{
  Value = "Test variable"
})
```

This will allow us to do 2 things:

- we can modify the string value without changing the *identity* of the object stored in `$test1`,
- string value can be modified by multiple background threads without any race conditions occuring

Now we just need to create the closure from the `$Action` block:

```
$Action = {
    Write-Host $test1.Value
}.GetNewClosure()
```

This will bind the value of `$test1` (the reference to the synchronized hashtable we just created on the line above) to the `$Action` block, and it will therefore "remember" that `$test1` resolves to the hashtable rather than attempt (and fail) to resolve it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been unable to make this work, as it just prints a blank space (same problem I had before). Maybe I'm missing something. Only changes I made were the two code blocks you listed.